# Online instructional videos for crack climbing

Tags: rock-climbing, crack-climbing

For technical face climbing, there are some really good online instructional [videos](https://www.youtube.com/user/Cruxfilmsclimbing) (on youtube) by Neil Gresham. Can anyone recommend similar instructional videos for crack technique?

Comment: related: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/11385/online-instructional-videos-for-slab-climbing

Comment: Oops, so this was a total duplicate of this: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5299/climbing-through-the-cracks/5301

Comment: I did not think it was a duplicate, just really similar.  But I see that all the links in my answer are dead now! :-(  I'll have to see if I can fix that tomorrow.

Comment: This is being closed because it is asking exclusively for offsite links. This presents a number of problems for the Q&A. If you'd like to discuss, please catch me in chat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wild country crack school is a great resource for learning how to climb cracks.
[Wild Country Crack School](https://vimeo.com/40346006)